# Setting up MockMvc with @WebMvcTest in Spring Boot 1.4 MVC Testing

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-mvc-test

I have few working code to set up `MockMVc` in different ways with the new Spring Boot 1.4 `@WebMvcTest`. I understand the standaloneSetup approach. What I want to know is the difference between setting up `MockMvc` through `WebApplicationContext` and by autowiring `MockMvc`.

**Code Snippet 1: MockMvc through WebApplicationContext Setup**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ProductController.class)
public class ProductControllerTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@MockBean
private ProductService productServiceMock;

@Before
public void setUp() {
     mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
}

@Test
public void testShowProduct() throws Exception {      

    Product product1 = new Product();
    /*Code to initialize product1*/

    when(productServiceMock.getProductById(1)).thenReturn(product1);

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/product/{id}/", 1))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            /*Other expectations*/
            .andReturn();
  }
}
```

As per `WebMvcTest` API documentation, *By default, tests annotated with @WebMvcTest will also auto-configure Spring Security and MockMvc*. So, I expected a 401 Unauthorized status code here, but the test passes with a 200 status code.

Next, I tried auto wiring `MockMvc`, but the test fails with 401 Unauthorized status code, unless I add `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure=false)` or update the `@WebMvcTest` annotation to disable security:

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = IndexController.class, secure = false)
```

Following is the code that passes ONLY AFTER explicitly disabling security.
**Code Snippet 2: MockMvc through Autowiring**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ProductController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure=false)
public class ProductControllerTest {
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
@MockBean
private ProductService productServiceMock;

@Test
public void testShowProduct() throws Exception {      

    Product product1 = new Product();
    /*Code to initialize product1*/

    when(productServiceMock.getProductById(1)).thenReturn(product1);

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/product/{id}/", 1))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            /*Other expectations*/
            .andReturn();
  }
}
```

So my questions are:

1. Why didn't Code snippet 1 report a a 401 Unauthorized status code error while auto wiring `MockMvc` did. Also reiterating what the official doc says  *By default, tests annotated with @WebMvcTest will also auto-configure Spring Security and MockMvc.* But, in this case it appears `@WebMvcTest` has nothing to do with auto-configuring Spring Security (Because Code Snippet 1 passes without any 401 error). It finally boils down to how I set up the `MockMvc`. Am I correct here?
2. What are the differences/objectives between/of both the approaches?
3. How does disabling security via `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure=false)` differs from doing through  `@WebMvcTest(controllers = IndexController.class, secure = false)`. Which one is the preferred approached or when (or where) to use them?

Answer (score 11):

I also come across similar problem. `@WebMvcTest` auto configures Spring Security with basic auth but I have a `WebSecurityConfig` class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.` In this class I disabled basic auth and configured token base security. That means `WebSecurityConfig` class is not used to configure Spring Security.

To resolve the problem, I added `@ContextConfiguration` to my unit test class and added mocks of dependencies of `WebSecurityConfig` class.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = CategoryRestService.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MjApplication.class, WebSecurityConfig.class})
public class CategoryRestServiceTest {
    
    @MockBean
    private CategoryRepository repository;
    
    @MockBean
    CurrentUserDetailsService currentUserDetailsService;
    
    @MockBean
    TokenAuthProvider tokenAuthProvider;
    
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    private MediaType contentType = new    MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getType(),
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getSubtype(), Charset.forName("utf8"));
    
    
    @Test
    public void getCategories() throws Exception {
        Category category1 = new Category();
        category1.setName("Test Category 1");
        category1.setId(1L);
        Category category2 = new Category();
        category2.setName("Test Category 2");
        category2.setId(2L);
        List<Category> categoryList = new ArrayList<Category>();
        categoryList.add(category1);
        categoryList.add(category2);
        given(this.repository.findAll())
        .willReturn(categoryList);
        mockMvc.perform(get("/public/rest/category"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(contentType))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].id", is(1)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].name", is("Test Category 1")))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].id", is(2)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].name", is("Test Category 2")));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

According to this issue in github

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5476

@WebMvcTest auto configures by default, a basic auth when spring-security-test is in the class path

Answering your questions:

1. In the code snippet 1, you not injected the MockMvc in your test class, you should add .apply(springSecurity()) in the builder on the setup method, so spring would use the basic configuration (not your custom security configuration if you have one)
2. both approaches does basically the same thing, the difference is that the second comes with the basic auth already in the MockMvc, that is why you have to use the secure=false
3. From the documentation:

> By default, tests annotated with @WebMvcTest will also auto-configure
>   Spring Security and MockMvc (include support for HtmlUnit WebClient
>   and Selenium WebDriver). For more fine-grained control of MockMVC the
>   @AutoConfigureMockMvc annotation can be used.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure this is directly related, but there is an [outstanding bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6514) where, if using spring boot and `@WebMvcTest`, your custom `@EnableWebSecurity` config class will be ignored. A couple workarounds are mentioned in the bug report. I'm using:

```
@WebMvcTest(includeFilters = @Filter(classes = EnableWebSecurity.class))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is correct way or not but I could disable configurations class by using like below

```
@WebMvcTest(ProductController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ProductController.class)
public class ProductControllerTest {
  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @MockBean
  private ProductService productServiceMock;
```